# Exclude arrays with bad status

Tags: arrays, bash, perl, awk, operators

I have three variables in array, want to skip those which are with "unknown" status, but anyway to show up in the output till the end:

Arrays:

```
VAR=("db1 active 10.0.0.11" "db2 active 10.0.0.12" "db3 inactive unknown" "db4 active 10.0.0.14" "db5 inactive unknown" )
```

CMD:

```
for i in "${VAR[@]}"; do read -r a b c <<< "$i";if [ -z "$c" ];then echo bad;elif [ ! -z "$c" ];then ssh $c "cat /backup/$a/backup.status";fi;done
```

Sample output of `cat backup.status` in db1:

```
$cat /backup/db1/backup.status
$Backup Complete
```

Current Output:

```
Backup Complete
Backup Complete
Backup Complete
```

I haven't figured out how to catch the `$c` variable to skip in the first sentence where the ssh command is but to add it after everything is complete from the active databases.

Desired Output:

```
Backup Complete
Backup Complete
Backup Complete
Database db3 not reachable
Database db5 not reachable
```

Answer (score 3):

`[ -z "$c" ]` is true if the variable is empty. But it's never empty, is either an ip, or "unknown".

You can change the condition to

```
if [ "$c" = unknown ] ; then
```

or change the assignment to

```
VAR=('db1 active 10.0.0.11'
     'db2 active 10.0.0.12'
     'db3 inactive'
     'db4 active 10.0.0.14'
     'db5 inactive'
)
```

Comment: When I use `if [ "$c" = unknown ] ; then` is not perform the ssh command

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you want. Please be more specific.

Comment: Ok, I find my mistake in my first try's I use `if [ "$c" = unknown ] ; then` but after that I put exit 1, which make the whole mess.